# Selected tab in jQuery tab script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery tab script that gets content from a PHP file defined by the link and parses it to a div element. When the page loads up, a tab is already selected and the user can select an alternative one. However, when you click anywhere other than on a tab, the selected tab is removed. Why could this be?

This is my current jQuery code:

```
function load(url){
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        success:function(message){
            $("#content").html(message);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id]").click(function(){
        type=$(this).attr("id");
        url=""+type+".php";
        $("[id]").removeClass("selected");
        $("#"+type).addClass("selected");
        load(url);
        return false;
    });
    $("#tab1").click();
});
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<ul> 
<li><a id="tab1" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab1</a></li> 
<li><a id="tab2" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab2</a></li> 
<li><a id="tab3" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery selector says to target all elements with an id tag. Any element on the page with an id tag will have the click handler assigned. It's either that, or the fact that in javascript, all elements have an id attribute. It is just usually set to null/empty. So the selector essentially targets all tags. In the end, it is roughly the same thing. I would suggest making a convention (like you already have) and start each tab with a word like `tab_` and then in the jquery selector use something like `[id^="tab_"]`. Then the selector will get all elements that start with `tab_`.

Answer (score 0):

having a better and easy to use tab jquery script for your reference

http://creativealive.com/easy-to-use-jquery-tabs-css-jquery/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks but that i found relivent